# Separation of channels in simple audio LED VU meter

Tags: audio, basic

I'm trying to build a very simple VU meter based on LEDs and transistors. I used [this tutorial](https://www.eleccircuit.com/led-vu-meter-circuit-by-transistor/#20_LED_VU_meter_schematic) as a base - basically I copied the LED array setup but replaced the input with full bridge rectifier. My signal input circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdfWrR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Overall I understand how this circuit works. I built one channel and it works as expected. However, my goal is to have a stereo indicator with common power supply. So I built the second channel the same way, with common ground. However, I noticed a weird thing: I tested the circuit with 1Hz sine wave and noticed, that when I turn the balance all the way to the right channel the right channel lights every 0.5s, which is expected. However, the left channel also lights up but every 1s, as if it's receiving half of the cycle as input. Understantably, for higher frequencies just both of the channels light up, regardless of which channel receives the input signal.

My question is: why and how does this happen?

Side note: please bear with me if this question is silly, I just recently picked up electronics as a side hobby and am still struggling a bit. I have tried to find information about this but I don't even know what to look for.

Comment: You might want to draw the second channel into the picture to see better how it is connected - but both left and right channels of your source share the same common (ground) so those will be connected together even before the diode bridge. And since they share the power supply as well, they have common ground. Maybe you will see it also better when you draw the full schematics with both channels.

Comment: The bridge rectifier is a mistake, unless your input signals are fully isolated (e.g. transformer coupled balanced signals in the pro audio world.) Just use half wave rectifiers with the "cold" leg of the input grounded. Other channel is teh same, and can then share the same ground.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It seems I don't quite grasp how stereo audio signal is transmitted. I see that the ground is common but headphones share common ground too, right? How come I don't hear anything in other channel if I set the balance to just one of them? How would half-bridge rectifier help with this situation? Would it help if I put an op-amp buffer for each channel before the rectifier?

Comment: Something clicked and I think I get it now - since I'm using the full-bridge rectifiers with common grounds, the negative voltage from one channel causes positive voltage after the rectifier on the other channel. Hence I get only pulses every 1 second (half-wave) on one channel and 0.5s pulses (full-wave) on the other. Please correct me if I'm wrong, otherwise - thank you!

Comment: Don't test at 1 Hz - it's pointless and, as said, use a half wave rectifier.